# Negative rewrite rule for redirecting everything that's not an image?

Tags: regex, string, apache, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create an Apache rewrite rule that redirects everything that **is not** an image file to a specific script, but I've been unable to make it work with ^ and negative lookaheads. Basically the following one matches if it **is** an image, but I am not sure how to make it negative.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*\.(png|bmp|jpg|gif))$
RewriteRule .* ./not-an-image.php
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `!` to make it a reverse the match.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(.*\.(png|bmp|jpg|gif))$
```